# Creating matrix with two different tables with no common key

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I want to create a matrix in PowerBI based on two tables that do not have a common key and I am grateful for any help.

Table 1 looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, it contains a specific hirachy.

Table 2 looks like this (excerpt):

[image]

As you can see, each category, subcategory and subsubcategory is a column on its own in Table 2.

The goal is to have all the categories, subcategories, and sub-subcategories from Table 1 with their respective hirachie as rows in the matrix, the customers (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5) in the columns, and the values from Table 2 as the values. The result should look something like this:

[image]

I have created a PowerBI file with examplary data: [PowerBi file](https://github.com/Hatico90/test/blob/main/Examplary%20Data.pbix?raw=true)

Does anyone have a good idea how this solution can be archived? Any help is welcome. ‌‌

Best regards,
Fabi

Comment: There is no way to tell where your desired output is coming from because those numbers are not shown in the input table. Provide sample input that matches the output and better explain where the numbers are coming from.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have updated the "matrix" showing what the result should look like. The input now matches the output. The values in the matrix are from table 2. Does this make things clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using M/Powerquery:

Code for Table1; creates a sorted hierarchy with an index

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Index", "Index.1", 0.1, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Index2" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Index1", "Index.2", 0.11, 1, Int64.Type),

#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Added Index2", {"Category"}),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Removed Duplicates",{"Category", "Index"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Level", each ""),

#"Removed Duplicates2" = Table.Distinct(#"Added Index2", {"Subcategory"}),
#"Removed Other Columns2" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Removed Duplicates2",{"Subcategory", "Index.1"}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns2", "Level", each "     "),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom1",{{"Index.1", "Index"}, {"Subcategory", "Category"}}),

#"Removed Other Columns3" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Index2",{"Subsubcategory", "Index.2"}),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns3", "Level", each "          "),
#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom2",{{"Index.2", "Index"}, {"Subsubcategory", "Category"}}),

combined =  #"Added Custom" & #"Renamed Columns" & #"Renamed Columns1",
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(combined,{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Added Index3" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index.1", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index3", "Hierarchy", each [Level]&[Category])

in #"Added Custom3"
```

Code for Table2 (becomes output)

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Customer"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Attribute"}, Table1, {"Category"}, "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table1", {"Index.1", "Hierarchy"}, {"Index.1", "Hierarchy"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded Table2", List.Distinct(#"Expanded Table2"[Customer]), "Customer", "Value"),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Index.1", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Attribute", "Index.1"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

could also code Table2 as starting with a headers to row, then transpose

[image]

Comment: Thank you @horseyride for the reply which looks very promising. Could you please provide the .pbix file as well?

Comment: I dont have a pbix, sorry. Desktop powerquery in use here

Comment: No problem. I was able to recreate your solution. It is an very interesting way of solving this! However, (and I have to admit, this was not very clear from my first post) it does not allow to collapse and expand hirachies in a PowerBI matrix. Do you have an easy fix for this in mind?

Comment: Sorry, no I do not. Pehaps create another level column instead of the spaces and merge that in to the other table  and use that

Comment: Okay, Ill try his. Even if its not the perfect soloution to my problem, its a 100% solution to what I was asking for in the post. So thanks! I created a new question with a bit more context; just in case you have some additional ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72450827/powerbi-creating-a-matrix-with-text-values